# echo out search query results to new page?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a search script which i am using, basically when a user types in a query i.e. london or a users age 5 results are shown out of how ever many results are found. The reason i have limited it to five is because of the lack of space.

I am trying to make a button that appears at the bottom of the search results that says view more similar results. This basically would link to a new page and echo out the query that was originally typed by the user, so at first they type in london and five users with the result london are shown, then if they click the links all of the results for london are shown on the new page.

Does anyone know how i can echo a query or do something similar which is going to give me the desired effect i need.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
//PHP CODE STARTS HERE

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="";
$db_tb_atr_name="display_name";

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);


$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_stats
                        WHERE display_name like '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR age LIKE '%".$query."%' OR nationality LIKE '%".$query."%' OR ethnicity LIKE '%".$query."%' OR hobbies LIKE '%".$query."%' OR station LIKE '%".$query."%' LIMIT 5");
echo "<div class=\"search-results\">";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))

{

    echo "<div class=\"text\"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$data_fetch['user_id']}\" class=\"search\">";
    echo "<div class=\"spacing\"><img width=35px height= 30px src=\"data/photos/{$data_fetch['user_id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgridsearch\"/> "; 
     echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
    echo "</a></div></div>";

}
echo "<div class=\"morebutton-search\"><a href=\"search.php?to=echo '%".$query."%'\" target=\"_blank\" \">+ view more results</a></div>";


mysql_close();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but you're stuck in cargo-cult programming mode.

1) `"$db_host"` is pointless. Build a new string just to hold some other string in its entirety? `$db_host` without quotes (and simillarly for the other variables) is all that's needed.

2) `echo` is a language construct. It has no return value, and you cannot concatenate its "results" together. You've also embedded in the echo inside a string, preventing PHP from even seeing it as an output directive:

```
echo "[...snip...]<a href=\"search.php?to=%$query%\" target=[...snip...]";
```

is all that's needed. You do not have to "break" out of a double-quoted string for a variable.
And for multi-line string echoes, you really should be using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) instead, which makes for far more legible code.

Comment: thanks, any idea's what my search.php paid should look like in order to echo out the results?